# Specific spring-core jar to be included in project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, netbeans

Ive included following lines in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The specific `spring-core` JAR version I want is 4.1.6, but whenever I do an `mvn clean install`, the dependencies folder under my project in netbeans shows a downgraded version (currently 3.0.7.RELEASE).

I want to know how I can force maven to put 4.1.6.RELEASE jar in my dependencies folder. I've done

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DactTransitively=false -DreResolve=false
```

And I've the folder 4.1.6.RELEASE with correct jar in my local `/.m2/repositories` folder. I need to access `org.springframework.util.MimeType` class which is not available in spring-core 3.0.7.RELEASE jar.

Comment: Post the result of `mvn dependency:tree` to see where that dependency is being pulled from.

Answer (score 0):

See the result of mvn dependency:tree to know if another jar bring back the version 3.0.7. and exclude from this dependency the spring-core

See the same result to know if the right version is present

Add the pom.xml and the result of mvn dependency:tree in the question

Comment: which is actually what Tunaki mentioned in his comment

Comment: Hi, im getting this when i do mvn dependency: tree

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) on project BaseBuild: Cannot build project dependency graph: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:BaseBuild:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RC2, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.0.RC2, org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.0.RC2: Could not find artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RC2 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1. Check in .m2 local repository where the Spring 3.0.7 jar is downloaded(It should be under folder org->springframework)
2. Delete the folder present inside springframework, so that mvn will try to fetch required dependencies.
   Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that spring-core is a mandatory dependenecy of most spring artifacts. Most likely you are using a dependent artifact e.g spring-context which is of version  3.0.7. Then Maven is fetching spring-core of the same version as the dependent artifact using its transitive dependency mechanism.

To control the version of spring-core you need to move its declaration from the dependencies section to the dependency management section of your pom.xml as follows

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.6</version>
            </dependency>
       </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```